# Generating source code with jaxws-maven-plugin from WSDL over HTTPS

Tags: java, maven, jaxws-maven-plugin

I am generating source code with jaxws-maven-plugin over HTTPS:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>wsdl_new_xxx-exec</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated</sourceDestDir>
            <args>
                <arg>-B-XautoNameResolution</arg>
            </args>
            <wsdlUrls>
                <wsdlUrl>https://example.com/xxx.asmx?WSDL</wsdlUrl>
            </wsdlUrls>
            <packageName>x.y.z</packageName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

But during the build time I get:

> [ERROR] sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
>   failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to find valid c ertification path to requested target

I know that a solution to that is to add the cert to the JRE keystore but the problem is that this is going to run on a CI system which has tons of possible nodes over which I don't have control and therefore cannot install the cert to all nodes' JREs.

How I can solve this? Without resorting to having WSDL files along with the pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution : store a local copy of the WSDL in your `src/main/resources` directory and use it as reference for the`jaxws-maven-plugin`.